# Laravel send mail

Tags: laravel, symfony, email, php-8.1

I'm trying to send an email and I get this error

`Typed property Symfony\Component\Mailer\Transport\AbstractTransport::$dispatcher must not be accessed before initialization`

`use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail; use App\Mail\Signups as MailSignup;`

```
Route::get('/test_mail', function (){
    Mail::to('test@mail.com')->send(new MailSignup(array('field' => null), 'Test subject'));
});
```

This is the stack trace, it uses just Laravel packages, no custom code beside the route.

[image]

It broke after I updated with `composer update` and `composer upgrade`

Comment: your laravel version?

Comment: Do not upload image of your code instead write the relevant code inside in question.

Comment: @sta `Laravel Framework 9.39.0`

Comment: @LeenaPatel I've included a picture since it's a vendor package, not code I have written. Have included it to show the stack trace, from the route to the file with the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize `MailSignup` before calling `send()` in route

```
Route::get('/test_mail', function (){
   $mailsignup = new MailSignup(array('field' => null), 'Test subject');
   Mail::to('test@mail.com')->send($mailsignup);
});
```

Comment: But that's a package `vendor / symfony / mailer / Transport / AbstractTransport.php`, I should not edit files in vendor folder.